# Percentage between two dates compared to today

Tags: javascript

I am creating a UI which will contain Milestones and I will be using a progress bar to show this.

I am trying to come up with the percentage we are from the date the milestone is set to be completed vs today's date.

For example if I have a milestone called "Live to Site" that is set to happen on December 1, 2015, and I put the milestone in on Jan 1st, I want to determine the percentage we are from the start date to the end date.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz4c16fx/2/

```
var start = new Date(2015,0,1), // Jan 1, 2015 - The date we put this milestone in
    end = new Date(2015,7,24), // June 24, 2015 - The date the milestone is due
    today = new Date(), // April 23, 2015
    p = Math.round(100-((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%';

// Update the progress bar
$('.bar').css( "width", p ).after().append(p);
```

That was my attempt at it but either my math is wrong or I am thinking about this incorrectly. The number its returning is `99%`. I feel that number should be lower seeing how we have 1.5 months left from today.

My end result is to show a progress bar that show how close we are to the completion date given the start, end and today's date.

Comment: if you are using node js you can use `moment js` package. It have many fuctions like `time from now` or `subtract`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var start = new Date(2015, 0, 1), // Jan 1, 2015
    end = new Date(2015, 7, 24), // August 24, 2015
    today = new Date(), // April 23, 2015
    p = Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100) + '%';
// Update the progress bar
$('.bar').css("width", p).after().append(p);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zz4c16fx/6/

Comment: So yours also returns 99% but that just doesn't seem right to me. Mine also came out with that result- is it accurate and I am just not thinking clearly? Shouldn't this be in the 80's?

Comment: Oh, your fiddle was the link to my OP :)

Comment: Converted to C# .NET and have confirmed that the logic to set "p" works.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, convert the end and start date to unit timestamp values.

```
// Convert to unix values timestamp values
var startDate = start.getTime();
var endDate = end.getTime();
var todayDate = today.getTime();

// Get the total possible timestamp value
var total = endDate - startDate;

// Get the current value
var current = todayDate - startDate;

// Get the percentage
var percentage = (current / total) * 100;

alert(percentage);
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x3snbz2w/2/

Comment: Date objects will be coerced to numbers implicitly when used with mathematical operators. And X/Y === (X/1000) / (Y/1000) so there's no point converting to seconds.

Comment: You can remove the first 4 lines altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To get the percentage of days elapsed thus far between one date and another, you need to calculate the time between start and end, then calculate the time between start and today. Then divide the second number by the first:

```
var start = new Date(2015,0,1),
    end = new Date(2015,7,24), 
    today = new Date();

var timeBetweenStartAndEnd = (end - start); 
var timeBetweenStartAndToday = (today - start);

var p = Math.round(timeBetweenStartAndToday / timeBetweenStartAndEnd * 100); 

console.log("Percentage of days elapsed thus far: " + p);
```