# Percentage between two dates compared to today in android/java

Tags: java, android, date, percentage, android-date

How I can find percentage between two dates compared to today in android/java?
This question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839270/percentage-between-two-dates-compared-to-today).

I want to do something like this:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    yeartoday = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    monthtoday = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    daytoday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
...

    Date datestart = getDate(styear,(stmonth-1),stday);
    Date dateend = getDate(year,(month-1),day);
    Date datetoday = getDate(yeartoday,monthtoday,daytoday);
    double percent = (((datetoday - datestart) / (dateend - datestart)) * 100);
...
public Date getDate(int year,int month,int day){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: I think the only problem with your code is the time returned by `getDate` is a `Date` and not a `double`. you have can obtain the current milliseconds of the date with `Calendar#timeInMillis` or with `Date#time`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I did:

```
    double millisstart = datestart.getTime();
    double millisend = dateend.getTime();
    double millistoday = datetoday.getTime();
    double percent = (((millistoday - millisstart) / (millisend - millisstart)) * 100);
    percentAsString = Double.toString(percent);

    txt5.setText(percentAsString);
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , today ) * 100 ) 
/ 
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop )
```

## java.time

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Elapsed days

You seem to want a percentage based on number of days. To get a count of elapsed days, use the [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) method on the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS) enum class.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( earlier , later ) ;
```

With a pair of these integers, you can calculate your percentage.

### Example

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate start = today.minusDays( 5 ) ;
LocalDate stop = today.plusDays( 15 ) ;

long totalDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
long elapsedDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , today ) ;

long percentComplete = ( elapsedDays * 100 ) / totalDays ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "start.toString(): " + start ) ;
System.out.println( "today.toString(): " + today ) ;
System.out.println( "stop.toString(): " + stop ) ;
System.out.println( "totalDays: " + totalDays ) ;
System.out.println( "elapsedDays: " + elapsedDays ) ;
System.out.println( percentComplete + "%" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/u2A6az).

> start.toString(): 2019-06-04
>
> today.toString(): 2019-06-09
>
> stop.toString(): 2019-06-24
>
> totalDays: 20
>
> elapsedDays: 5
>
> 25%

### Validate inputs

Of course, for real work you need to do a bit more.

You should verify that the start is before the stop.

```
boolean startIsBeforeStop = start.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

You need to verify that today is between the pair of dates.

```
boolean todayIsWithinRange = ( ! today.isBefore( start ) ) && today.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

#### *ThreeTen-Extra*

If your work often involves date ranges, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This gives you the handy [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

```
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
boolean startIsBeforeStop = ( range.lengthInDays() > 0 ) ; // A negative number beens the start is *not* before the stop.
boolean todayIsWithinRange = range.contains( today ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).